# Best way to view a command return code in DOS

Tags: windows, cmd, errorlevel, return-code

Sometimes I run a command in `cmd` such as:

```
fc /b file1 file2
```

and would like to see the return code from fc.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

From TechNet, [Command shell overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490954.aspx):
*"%ERRORLEVEL% ... Returns the error code of the most recently used command. A non zero value usually indicates an error."*

To test for specific error levels in batch files, you may find [this knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69576) useful.